# Rails, upload progress bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked at a number of resource for creating an upload progress bar in Rails using Passenger.

dromo's blog, swfupload, plus more. I haven't been able to get one working.

Any Rails people actually have a working example of successfully implementing upload progress bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, swfupload and uploadify both have ways to get them to work with Rails. The trick is to carry around some session variables.

[Uploadify and Rails 2.3](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/07/21/uploadify-and-rails23/)

[SWFUpload Paperclip and Rails](http://jimneath.org/2008/05/15/swfupload-paperclip-and-ruby-on-rails/)

[New Ruby on Rails demo app using SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/node/205)

Comment: possibly the railstips one. Looks good but comments had a lot of problems.

The jim neath one I've already tried and could not get that going. Comments seemed to have the same result that I had

Comment: I did the one using uploadify and it worked. It was a pain though.